# why my crawlspider doesn't work well?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want get some data from a website ,so i wrote a spider with scrapy ,but when i callback another "parse_zai",it seems to fail,so how can i finish it?please help !!

### the code is here

```
# encoding utf-8

from scrapy.http import Request

from scrapy.selector import Selector

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from tencentnews.items import TencentnewsItem
class Tencentnews_spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Tnews"
    allowed_domains = ["news.qq.com"]#It's the web i scrapyed
    start_urls = [
         "http://news.qq.com/china_index.shtml",
         "http://news.qq.com/world_index.shtml",
         "http://news.qq.com/society_index.shtml", 
             ]
    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/a/\d{8}/\d{6}\.htm',)),follow=True,callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/(.+)\.shtml', )), follow=True),
            ]
```

## the main

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = TencentnewsItem()


        item['articlename'] = sel.xpath("//div[@id='C-Main-Article-QQ']/div[1]/h1/text()").extract() #get the news'article  
        item['reportsource'] = sel.xpath("//span[@class='color-a-1']/a/text()").extract()
        item['articletime'] = sel.xpath("//span[@class='article-time']/text()").extract()
        item['commentnumber'] = sel.xpath("//a[@id='cmtNum']/text()").extract()
        item['commenturl'] = sel.xpath("//a[@id='cmtNum']/@href").extract()
        print repr(item).decode("unicode-escape") + '\n'
        for url in item['commenturl']:
            request = Request(url,callback = self.parse_zai)
            request.meta['item'] = item 
        return request

    def parse_zai(self,response):
        print 'helloworld'
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = response.meta['item']

        item['title'] = sel.xpath("//div[@class='bigTitle']/h1/a/text()").extract()

        print repr(item).decode("unicode-escape") + '\n'    
        return item
```

Comment: What does it mean "seems to fail"? What are the error messages you are getting?

Comment: after I check the website, I found that the `commenturl` domain `coral.qq.com/xxx` is now in the allowed_domains. Add the domain to allowed_domains, or just remove the allow_domains attribute.

Comment: because parse_zai don't return any results,even "helloworld",so sad!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to see that you have not used header

User agent is a string that browsers use to identify itself to the web server. It is sent on every HTTP request in the request header, and in the case of Scrapy, it identifies as the following;

---

```
   def header(self):
         headers =  {         
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36',
                'Accept': 'application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
        }
        return headers
```

---

---

```
Request(url,callback = self.parse_zai, headers = headers)
```

---

---

Using Python Print Logs in a File
If you want to print python logs in a file rather than on the console then we can do so using the basicConfig() method by providing filename and filemode as parameter.

The format of the message can be specified by using format parameter in basicConfig() method.

```
import logging    # first of all import the module

logging.basicConfig(filename='std.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.warning('This message will get logged on to a file')
```

---

---

1. First of all, simply import the logging module.
2. In the second step is to create and configure the logger.
3. In the third step, the format of the logger can also be set.
4. You can also set the level of the logger.

---

---

```
logger.debug("This is debug message") 
logger.info("This is information message") 
logger.warning("This is Warning message") 
logger.error("This is error message")
```

---

By using this you can also stored the output into the log file

you can use this link for more depth information
i am giving the some links of some website they have given the detailed information of user agent

https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/

Answer (score 0):

after I check the website, I found that the commenturl domain `coral.qq.com/xxx` is not in the 
allowed_domains.

Add the domain to allowed_domains, or just remove the allow_domains attribute.

You can check if your Request failed due to the allowed_domains, by filter your scrapy loglevel DEBUG log.

```
grep "DEBUG: Filtered offsite request" yourlogfile.log
```

btw, the log will print just the first domain not in the allowed_domains, for keep log clean.

```
DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.example.com': <GET http://www.example.com>
```

doc: [OffsiteMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=offsitemiddleware#scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try

Comment: Thanks for your help,I have solve the problem as what you said,("remove the allowed_domain attribute")